# Getting windows to recognize new SSD after cloning and swapping

Tags: ssd, windows-10, device-manager, disk-cloning

Today I cloned my SSD (some OCZ Vertex where Windows 10 x64 is installed) to a bigger SSD (some Crucial M500) then swapped the drives. (I followed this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/199068/how-to-upgrade-your-existing-hard-drive-in-under-an-hour/), pretty much step-by-step.)

Everything has gone smoothly except that when I go to Device Manager, the old SSD is still listed under Disk drives:

[image]

I have ran a benchmark with [AS SSD Benchmark](http://www.alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?download_id=9) and got numbers that match those for the Crucial M500. So does it matter that Device Manager has the wrong name? If I'd like Windows to recognize the new drive properly and display as such under Device Manager, how would I do that please?

Comment: @Psycogeek I tried what you said and it worked! Can you please turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would delete a miss marked ID as shown in the device manager by uninstalling it in the device manager , then rebooting. It would then be re-recognised and re-installed.  The uninstall action could be done while in a safe mode (or clean boot) booting.

You really want  a full backup of the system to revert to if anything went wrong. Without that full protection and ability to revert anything, I would rather leave it with a wrong name :-)

also if you show hidden devices you might see other stuff in there that could use a clean-up, again though you mess with that stuff when you have a backup first, then you can delete first without worry.